# How to set checked item in checkedlistbox with listbox - c#

Tags: c#, listbox, checked, checkedlistbox, checkeditems

I have problem to select item from `listbox` and check item in `checkedlistbox`.

How can I select item from `listbox` and then check in `checkedlistbox`?

[image: View My Project]

**I cant select listbox item and check checkedlistbox when match item**

**I want code for select checklistbox when item in listbox**

**How can check in checkedlistbox with textbox and seprated comma**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question right :

What you need is the method GetItemCheckState.

Usage as follows:

Try This :

```
  foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false);//First uncheck the old value!
                                                         //
                for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString() == listBox1.Items[x].ToString())
                    {
                        //Check only if they match! 
                        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: no , I want to set checked when item is in listbox

Comment: Can you clarify the question so I can edit the answer according to that ?

Comment: I have no idea to solve this problem

Comment: I want code for select checklistbox when item in listbox

Comment: values.Length is not in my project

Comment: use this code in my button click and no action

Comment: I edited the code again and tested it on my end. It works

Comment: thanks , code is good worked

Comment: my question is updated please check this

Comment: please help for next question

Comment: download my project

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygzr7axlhotg89n/checkItems.zip?dl=0

Comment: how select checked listbox from string seprated with comma

Comment: my string is "Brown,Green,Red,Violet"

Comment: Yes ===>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378515/how-to-set-checked-item-in-checkedlistbox-with-string-seprated-comma-c-sharp

Comment: My old Question when i set datasource to checkedlistbox is not worked

Comment: i use this sample code for connect to database

Comment: ((ListBox)chkList).DisplayMember = "SizeName";
((ListBox)chkList).ValueMember = "SizeID";
((ListBox)chkList).DataSource = _sizeList;

Comment: i dont this code is ok or not